# What is the probability of drawing a "conditionally" specific set of cards in a hand of 7?

Tags: probability

With the following specifics:

- Deck of 60 cards:
  4 copies of $\mathcal A$,
  3 copies of $\mathcal B$,
  16 copies of $\mathcal C$ and
  37 copies of $\mathcal Z$
- Hand of 7 cards drawn from the deck of 60, shuffled beforehand
- Order in the hand does not matter

#### 1. Preliminary Problem

As a first step, I'm trying to express the probability of drawing a hand of $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal Z$, $\mathcal Z$, $\mathcal Z$.

$$
P = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{16}{2}\binom{37}{3}}{\binom{60}{7}}
$$

If I was not to care about the 3 remaining cards (the 3 $\mathcal Z$) drawn in a way that they could be any combination of $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$ and/or $\mathcal Z$, how should I fix my caclulation?

#### 2. Follow-up Problem

Deck is now:
4 copies of $\mathcal A$,
3 copies of $\mathcal B$,
4 copies of $\mathcal C$,
12 copies of $\mathcal D$,
4 copies of $\mathcal E$,
15 copies of $\mathcal F$ and
18 copies of $\mathcal Z$

Now what if the *valid* cases I'm interested in are either:

- A hand of $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal E$, $\mathcal ?$, $\mathcal ?$
- A hand of $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal F
  $, $\mathcal ?$, $\mathcal ?$
- A hand of $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal D$, $\mathcal E$, $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal ?$

Do I just sum these 3 probabilities together or is there a less verbose/slow known way of doing it? For context, I have small Python script that calculates probability of the hand seen in 1. and there are many more scenarii than just these 3.

Comment: What does "the remaining $3$" mean?  You have specified seven cards,  Which ones do you want to drop off?

Comment: For (1) you have taken out 4 cards out of the pool. You have to choose 3 cards from the remaining =$\binom{56}{3}$

Comment: @lulu The 3 `Z` are the ones I don't care about. Edited

Comment: @NewGuy I have tried that and yet I don't have the same results as the ones given by http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx (with a simple example). With the following calculation: $P = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{59}{6}}{\binom{60}{7}}$, and the following input https://i.imgur.com/2WgDnD1.png

Comment: @lulu Capped as in: needed in the first 4 cards, and therefore cannot be found as a 3-of in the 3 remaining cards drawn?

Comment: I deleted my comment as I fear it falls into the same error as the other method sketched in the comments.  That is, it double counts cases in which the first $A_1$ is chosen as part of the initial four and $A_2$ is chosen as one of the extra three.

Comment: @Maathieu Marques Another interpretation of your problem can be you have to draw 7 cards such that you have to draw atleast 1 A ,1 B and 2 C?? Is this correct?

Comment: Different idea:  start by ignoring the restrictions.  That is, count the number of $4-$tuples that add to $7$.   Then use Inclusion-Exclusion to remove those cases that fail a restriction.  I think the unrestricted count is just $36$ types.  That could even be inspected by hand.

Comment: @NewGuy That 's correct.

Comment: On review:  my original idea works just fine as a way to count the number of patterns.  Then you have to populate them...just make sure you do the population on the entire pattern.

Comment: @lulu What does adding to 7 mean?

Comment: I'm posting something below.

Comment: @Maathieu Marques https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675615/number-of-ways-to-choose-k-balls-such-that-there-are-at-least-1-of-certain-c/2675789#comment5526512_2675789  Similar kind of question

Comment: I sketched what I was talking about below,  Not a full solution, but too long to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

Let the $4-$ tuple $(a,b,c,z)$ represent the number of cards of each type in your hand.  These are the patterns you wish to count.  Of course we must have $a+b+c+z=7$ but there are other restrictions as well.

The good hands satisfy:  $$4≥a≥1\quad 3≥b≥1\quad c≥2$$

We remark that we can drop the $4≥a$ restriction as it is implied by the others.

First step:  Just count the number of patterns.  Using the restrictions we see that we are trying to count the $4-$tuples $(a',b',c',z)$ of non-negative integers which add to $3$ and which satisfy $2≥b'$.  By [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) that count, without the $2≥b'$ constraint is given by $$\binom {7-1}3=20$$ substracting the single case with $b'=3$ we see that there are $19$ patterns to consider.  Not too bad.  we just have to enumerate these and count the ways to populate each. Defining $$a=a'+1\quad b=b'+1\quad c=c'+2$$ we remark that the number of ways to populate the pattern $(a,b,c,z)$ is $$\binom 4a\times \binom 3b\times \binom {16}c\times \binom {37}z$$

I don't see a quick way to simplify the sum.  Still, it's only $19$ terms.  It could be done by hand.

Added:  just did it by hand (mostly).  I got $$\boxed {19771136}$$  but I did it hastily and there could easily be blunders.

Remark:  might help an automated solution to note that defining $\binom nk=0$ when $k>n$ lets you ignore the cap on $b'$ (there would then be $0$ ways to populate that pattern).  For a more complex configuration this might simplify the coding.

Comment: Asking as I read, what's $(a',b',c',z)$?

Comment: Is it the count for each $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal Z$ that are contained in the 3 remaining cards?

Comment: Yes.  In order to use Stars and Bars, we need to first assign the known cards.  Thus, the $4-$tuple $(1,1,0,1)$ which adds to $3$ would correspond to the hand $(2,2,2,1)$.

Comment: To stress:  I wouldn't trust my numerical answer without verification.  I did it too quickly.  But the method should be sound.

Comment: I also get that value. And this is the count of 7-cards hands that validate the initial requirements of $(1, 1, 2)$ correct?

Comment: Therefore, the probability of such hands is that count divided by $\binom{60}{7}$, still correct? This is surprisingly low.

Comment: Yes.  Hard to have insight on the probability.  It's weird to have even one $B$...The probability of having zero $B's$ is $\binom {57}7/\binom {60}7\approx 0.685$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot though. This is a different approach but it definitely answers my first problem. About the second one, do you have an opinion?

Comment: I'd proceed as I did here, more or less.  Note:  you have overlap between your cases.  $ABCCDEF$ comes up in all three types for example.  So, you need to be careful.

Comment: Good catch, thanks a lot for the insights.